# Assigning multiple views to one viewmodel WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datacontext

I have an application where I assign each of the views datacontext through the datatemplate in xaml.

The problem is I now have a viewmodel implemented as a singleton and need to have two views using it.

Is there some way to set multiple views in the one datatemplate?

Something like below which I know does not work, I am just using this as an example of what I mean:

```
              <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ThisViewModel}">
                    <view:ViewOne />
                    <view:ViewTwo />
              </DataTemplate>
```

Thanks

Comment: please do check answers and comments on them, clarification was requested and never given, nor was an answer accepted. I would suggest updating your question to clarify and stating which approach you selected (and accept an answer)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if I understand you entirely, but it sounds like you need to assign a Key to your DataTemplates

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1" DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ThisViewModel}">
        <view:ViewOne />
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate2" DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ThisViewModel}">
        <view:ViewTwo />
  </DataTemplate>
```

Then from your regular XAML, you would specify what template you want to use for each area via it's key, like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyViewModel}" 
                ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}" />

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModels}" 
              ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate2}" />
```

---

If I misunderstood and you actually want one data template containing two Views, there's no problem with that. DataTemplates can have as many elements as you want, however they can only have one main child element, so make that element a panel that is used to tell WPF how to arrange the two views.

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1" DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ThisViewModel}">
      <StackPanel>
          <view:ViewOne />
          <view:ViewTwo />
      </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Sounds like, He want to add two views in one `DataTemplate` which share the `ViewModel `.

Comment: @AbinMathew Ah, I've edited my answer to include that if that is what OP wants. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to add two `Views` to a `DataTemplate` like below,

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="KeyName" DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ThisViewModel}">
    <Grid>
      <view:ViewOne />
      <view:ViewTwo />
    </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

`DataTemplate` can have more than one view by adding any kind of `Panel` as a parent Control, like `Grid`, `StackPanel`, `WrapPanel` etc all based on how you want to display it on the View.